# php - Laravel : Class 'Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider' not found after updating composer

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-socialite

So I'm new to Laravel and been following the Laracasts series on Laravel.

I cloned an open source Laravel Project, It doesn't have 'Vendor' Directory' , I was told to run 'composer update' in the root of the project to include it.
I do that and I get the error:

```
 [ErrorException]
copy(/home/sanyam/.composer/cache/files/laravel/socialite/fc3ff90cae77020dba2dc23168bebe2313c43051.zip): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

I tried to run the website locally and the terminal gave the error:

```
Class 'Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider' not found in /home/sanyam/projectname-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 150
```

Here is the deal, I can't edit any code in congif/app.php or anywhere because the project is up and running.
The last time it happened, I was missing the curl extension in PHP, installed it and it worked. This time I've tried clearing the cache using `composer dump-autoload` (doesn't work)

What am I supposed to do ?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Try `composer update --no-scripts`.

Comment: @Devon, Hi, yes I tried running it, at first it gave me a weird error and it didn't do anything. I tried at it again and this time it ran but again finally gave me the error 'copy(/home/sanyam/.composer/cache/files/laravel/socialite/fc3ff90cae77020db  
  a2dc23168bebe2313c43051.zip): failed to open stream: Permission denied       
                                                                        '

Comment: @SanyamPhirani seems like the user doesn't have permissions in the running directory.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thank you for the suggestion. But I get the same error, Permission denied.

Comment: Ah, I missed that in your question. The permissions issues are likely due to running Composer as a different user than the original installation. Ask whoever set it up the first time.

Comment: @ceejayoz Oh ! I didn't know that, Thank you :) 
But I don't know why I tried  [ sudo composer update --no-scripts ] 
and it worked. Thank you so much for you help. Appreciate it.

Comment: @SanyamPhirani Consider running `chown -R sanyam /home/sanyam/.composer` to fix the ownership of that folder. You will likely need to do that to your `vendor` directory too, as its files are owned by root now too.